# How to write your own basic disk scanner

Tags: c, windows, file-io

I would like to write some basic disk scanner utility. Basically I would like to be able to read raw bytes of a certain file(s) as written to the disk in the way system's disk utilities (like error checking and defragmentation in windows) do it. I would like to do it in C.

What should be my first steps? Obviously fopen is not enough.

Any guidance would be much appreciated (I don't ask for a solution, just a bit of theory and push in a right direction as I don't even know where to start from...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following resources might be of use:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawsectorio.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are venturing into the land of the driver here.  Most of the file access APIs still hold you at a level higher than the disk itself.  You could be talking to a file system on a CD, a RAMDisk, a SAN or HDD and you shouldn't care.

If you need to hit the disk directly then the Volume Managment API should help you out on Windows:

[Volume Management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365728%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

fopen and fread will work. If you want to use an unbuffered interface, use [open](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open) and [read](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read) instead. Open and read are part of the POSIX standard, so they work in Windows too, although you may want to find manual pages for windows to be sure to catch any subtle differences in behaviour.

Comment: **fopen** and **fread** let me read contents of a file, but the question is about all the additional data that is stored with every file on the disk in addition to its contents. Empty thus supposedly 0b long text file is still recognised by the system, along with its name and location on disk, therefore, it can't be 0b long, don't you think? File is [contents + something] and I want to read this something.

Comment: You can access the metadata using calls such as readdir(*nix) or FindFirstFile(windows).

Comment: Thanks @Klas. FindFirstFile will indeed give me some additional data about the file but it's not what I need. I want to have access to raw data written to disk not to metadata handled by the system first. What aix said is more on the topic.